# Android - Does SimpleCursorAdapter allow multiple layouts like BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, adapter, simplecursoradapter

I know you can create a custom `Adapter` extending `BaseAdapter` and create various layouts which can be inflated depending on which row the `AdapterView` is at..

But is there any way to get a simple amount of customization with a `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Eg. I have a database and I would like to query it and return the results to a `ListView` with alternating row layouts.

Will `SimpleCursorAdapter` do? Or are there any elegant solutions for this?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But is there any way to get a simple amount of customization with a SimpleCursorAdapter?

Just like BaseAdapter, you can extend CursorAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter to do your customization.

> Eg. I have a database and I would like to query it and return the results to a ListView with alternating row layouts.

If you are only alternating a minor thing like row color, you can simply override `bindView()` and check `if(cursor.getPosition() % 2 == 0)` (or `== 1`) to set the appropriate background color.

If you are using different types of or numbers of Views in each layout, you need to override `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`. Then use `getItemViewType()` in `newView()` to load the appropriate layout and in `bindView()` to display the appropriate data.

Comment: So `CursorAdapter` instead of `SimpleCursorAdapter`?  Most likely will be just row colour and therefore it is good to know about the simpler bindView() - cheers.

Comment: You can extend SimpleCursorAdapter, but if you look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java#SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView%28android.view.View%2Candroid.content.Context%2Candroid.database.Cursor%29) SimpleCursorAdapter performs a lot of checks (for instance, is the layout an TextView or ImageView or something else) on _every_ row _every_ time... So depending on your code you can create a faster class by overriding CursorAdapter. But either will work.